# How do I handle an event from a dynamically generated button using a modal dialog popup and custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events

I have a custom control that has a search function. When the user clicks search, the code generates a list of buttons based on the results of the search.

Each button's CommandArgument property contains the Id of the search result. When the user clicks the button, I want to handle the event, get the CommandArgument and raise an event back to the main page with the value.

The problem is that the buttons aren't raising the event. I would assume this is because it gets lost on a postback or whatever. Should I consider an alternative way of listing the values to make this work?

Whats the simplest way of getting around this? Here's what I have:

```
private void Search()
{
        foreach (var c in companies)
        {
            TableRow companyRow = new TableRow();
            TableCell nameRowCell = new TableCell();
            TableCell regRowCell = new TableCell();

            Button selectButton = new Button();
            selectButton.CommandArgument = c.Id.ToString();
            selectButton.Text = c.Name;
            selectButton.Click += new EventHandler(selectButton_Click);
            selectButton.CausesValidation = false;

            nameRowCell.Controls.Add(selectButton);
            companyRow.Cells.Add(nameRowCell);
            tblCompanies.Rows.Add(companyRow);

        }
}

    void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // <- Not getting handled
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        string id = btn.CommandArgument;
        if (id != "" && CompanyFound != null)
            CompanyFound(new Company() { Id = int.Parse(id) });
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, the custom control is in a panel for a modal dialog

Comment: I don't see you binding the handler to the buttons' click event anywhere. (?)

Comment: Missing `selectButton.Click += selectButton_Click;` in the code.

Comment: Sorry, it does exist - bad editing. Still no result though.

Comment: Do anything happen in firebug when you click on the button ? Can you check generated HTML and see if it calls __doPostback() ?

Comment: I installed FireBug but I can't see any __doPostback() calls... then again I probably don't know what I'm doing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing with your code and it does put a button on the screen. The browser source shows the button in the form of an input type submit tag. To test that it is in fact firing add a div to your page somewhere, maybe set it's id to testDiv. Then in your selectButton_Click event hander add a line to the effect of: testDiv.innerHtml = "made it here".

If the div changes, your button fired.

Also, maybe add protected, public or something before the void on the selectButton_Click.

Comment: I got it working eventually - I think it might have had something to do with event bubbling since I had user controls within user controls. I can't exactly remember what I did (because I went with another direction), but after I handled the event I set TextBox1.Text = whatever, and it never updated the text. This turned out to be an issue I had with the UpdatePanel. Once removed, it worked.